# swift - nodejs serialisation/deserialization

Tags: node.js, swift

I am trying to serialise a NSObject type from Swift and read it in NodeJS. I am two weeks old programmer in Swift, so not well versed with the most appropriate
Syntax yet. I tried similar solution in .Net 6 using Xamarin in Mac, where I used NSJsonSerialization to directly serialise NSObject and it  works well there.

This is what I have done so far

1. Serialise the NSObject into NSDictionary (considering JSONSerialization requires that)
2. Convert NSDictionary to Serialized object using JSONSerialization
3. Map result to JSON String (step 2 returns bytes so have to convert it to JSON String)
4. Print the string to standard output and flush the result so NodeJS could receive it

Despite multiple attempts, I still cannot get it to work and seek help.

Swift Code

```
                func getWindowBy(windowNumber : Int) -> NSObject? {
                let values = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption.optionAll, 0)
                
                var windows : NSArray = []
                windows = values! as NSArray
                
                for window in windows {
                    var test : NSObject? = NSObject.init()
                    test = window as? NSObject
                    var number : Int = test?.value(forKey: "kCGWindowNumber") as! Int
                    
                    if (number == windowNumber) {
                        return test
                    }
                }
                
                return NSObject.init()
            }

               func event(e: NSEvent?) {
                let winNum : Int = 5
                
                // getWindowBy returns NSObject
                let window = getWindowBy(windowNumber: e?.windowNumber ?? winNum) 
                do {
                    
                    let canConvert = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(window)
                    print(canConvert) // returns true

                    let dict : [String : Any] = NSDictionary(dictionary: window as! [String : Any]) as! [String : Any]

                    let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.withoutEscapingSlashes) 
                   
                    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? String()
                    
                    print(jsonString)
                    fflush(__stdoutp)
                } catch {
                    print("error")
                }

            }
```

NodeJS

```
           ipc.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

            process.stdout.write(whatIsIt(data)); // checks the type of Object and finds that it is not String or Array or Object type

            process.stdout.write("received:" + data); // prints the data in correct format
            
            var obj = JSON.parse(obj); // this doesn't work
           }
```

What is printed at Console from stdout.write command above is -

{"kCGWindowIsOnscreen":true,"kCGWindowLayer":0,"kCGWindowNumber":4175,"kCGWindowStoreType":1,"kCGWindowOwnerName":"Xcode","kCGWindowAlpha":1,"kCGWindowSharingState":0,"kCGWindowOwnerPID":7871,"kCGWindowBounds":{"X":27,"Height":818,"Y":167,"Width":1400},"kCGWindowMemoryUsage":1232}

I understand that what is serialized is not meeting expectations of a JSON object, however, not sure what needs to be done at Swift to Serialise it correctly.

Will appreciate any suggestion

---

Edit:
Added getWindowBy function for clarity on the NSObject type that is returned and is serialised

Comment: It would help if you add the error you see.

Comment: `print("error")` -> `print("error: \(error)"). What is `let window`? What you gave is valid JSON according to JSONLint.

Comment: @Larme I also tried to just copy the printed object from Console and parse it to JSON and it works well. However, when it is received from Swift and I try to parse it, I do not see any result or any error that is printed to Console.

Comment: @BrahmaDev - I do not see any error during the parsing even if I wrap the call under try-catch block. I tried to stringify the 'data' object, I see it of the type "buffer" - {"type":"Buffer","data":[123,34,107,67,71,87,105,110,100,111,119,83,116,111,114,101,84,121,112,101,34,58,49,44,34,107,67,71,87,105,110,100,111,119,73,115,79,110,115,99,114,101,101,110,34,58,116,114,117,101,44,34,107,67,71,87,105,110,100,111,119,77,101,109,111,114,121,85,115,97,103,101,34,58,49,50,51,50,44,......

Comment: I converted the response to string and then desrialized it to JSON. Working!  var obj = JSON.parse(data.toString());